# Launch a pod in k8s to be used as terminal for the cluster

Tags: shell, kubernetes

I'd like to launch a pod which runs all the time in the cluster and it can be used by the users as a jump box for the k8s cluster. So I have created a `Deployment` and run a pod. However I'm not sure which should be the `CMD` for this container. I could use `/bin/bash` or /bin/sh` however when then the user wants to attach to it, it would create another shell inside the pod and I would not want this. Any suggestions?

**Update**

I've put as `CMD` the following one:

```
CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "trap : TERM INT; (while true; do sleep 1000; done) & wait" ]
```

When I try to attach to the pod I get this:

```
Unable to use a TTY - container test did not allocate one
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
```

And pressing enter doesn't help.

Comment: You can use tmux inside the container, the user then will not be able to create another shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a jump box why not specify the the `CMD` to be `sshd` just like [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/).

That should be able to allocate TTYs.